# usage of solr in ecommerce area what to index and what not to index

Tags: solr, information-retrieval, data-retrieval

I work in an e-commerce area dealing with a huge [300,000] no of products and related data like attributes, price, promotions, collections.

We are thinking to index all the information in solr and query from solr instead of any DB hits. We are thinking of going this way to provide good performance, easy sorting, and faceting features [some example]. We also have delta indexing for near real-time accuracy.

Is this a good decision or it should be a mix of solr and DB. Need some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on your requirement. Solr is not a full replacement to your RDBMS.

You can migrate the relevant or important data to solr from RDBMS using the DIH feature of solr.

Whatever searching you want to execute you can perform on the solr server by HTTP requests.

You can also achieve sorting and faceting with solr.

And yes Delta indexing is also possible in solr.

Your decision of migrating the search relevant data is correct in order to improve the search performance of your application.

Yes it should be mix of RDBMS and solr for your application.

Comment: Thanks Abhijit for the response. i also get it should be a mix but not clear on which should be in solr and which should not. is there any reference architecture with pros and cons, with which i can compare my situation and take a decision

Comment: solr is not full replacement of rdbms but upto what level ? for search it is pretty clear solr can be used, but while searching you get all information of products like attributes, assortment, prices and promotions.. you have to index that for search response, it helps in sorting faceting etc, why not use that information to send say while asking for a product information by querying with product id ?

Comment: Its upto every individuals that how they want to use solr...for searching is one primary thing...you can get the product information from it by querying for a specific product id as well...solr is a nosql type database where is does not support joins, transaction ...

Comment: you will have everything related to your application in your rdbms...I doubt you can segregate anything between solr and DB...some part of your DB which is core and relevant and required to be fetched faster ..you can copy to solr...